# Conditional Formatting - Excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, conditional-formatting

This is driving me nuts. I have a very simple set of rules I wish to use. The cells show an increase or decrease as a percentage of a previous result. I want:

If a percentage is above or equal to 1 display an up arrow
If a percentage is below 1 but above -1 display a horizontal arrow
If a percentage is below -1 display a down arrow.

As you can see from this screenshot despite the rule setting this clearly it's not following the rule at all.

[image: Formula and results]

Comment: try 0.01 and -0.01

Answer (score 1):

A percentage of 0...100% is a number in the range 0...1. So for example, 3.45% is 0.0345 as a number. In the conditionals you compare to numbers, and the formatting does work as expected. Compare to ">= 0.01" and ">= -0.01".